# How to invoke a long-time task without block the existing batch script?

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, batch-file

I have a long-time task implemented in Windows batch script need to be add to a existing Windows batch script, the requirement is the existing script should run just as before, without being slowed down by the added task.

I am thinking calling the task script in a Java thread might works, but there are some difficulties:

1. How to call windows batch script in a Java thread?
2. How to quit the Java program without stop the thread?

Maybe I was wrong from the start, could any one give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding Java code would complicate the task. You can run the additional batch file in a separate process by using the `start` command, and this might serve your purpose:

In first.bat:

```
@echo calling second.bat
start second.bat
@echo called second.bat
```

This will create a second command window. If you don't want that window to show up, you can use the /B parameter, as in `start /B second.bat`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add something like this to your existing batch script:

```
start long_script.bat
```